# Can I get a web UI for spark in my local browser , when I running instances on server?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I work at a place where, I have a laptop and everyday I connect to a remote server using shell, and do everything(run jupyter notebook,use pyspark for spark jobs) on the server.

I want to keep a log of all the server resources that I am using when I run my spark job(memory,cpu usage etc).
I though one way I could do this is my looking at web UI, but I cant connect to the web UI.

I got all the proeperties of my driver ip, port and everything using sc._conf.getAll()
I am running spark on Yarn client
 (u'spark.master', u'yarn-client'),
and tried those on web browser but could not connect.

Comment: It sounds like it may be a firewall issue, either at your company side or the remote server side. May be worth checking with the people managing the IT infrastructure.

Comment: What is the error? HTTP response code? Is it GSS exception? Would be great if can give some error details.